# Python django: How to call selenium.set_speed() with django LiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, django, binding, selenium, webdriver

To run my functional tests i use `LiveServerTestCase`.

I want to call `set_speed` (and other methods, `set_speed` is just an example) that aren't in the webdriver, but are in the selenium object.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html#module-selenium.selenium

my subclass of `LiveServerTestCase`

```
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(7)

        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # how to call selenium.selenium.set_speed() from here? how to get the ref to the selenium object?

        super(SeleniumLiveServerTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```

How to get that? I can't call the constructor on selenium, i think.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910900/implementing-webdriverbackedselenium-in-python) link. You may need to use Webdriver backed selenium to use setspeed method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. Setting the speed in WebDriver is not possible and the reason for this is that you generally shouldn't need to, and the 'waiting' is now done at a different level.

Before it was possible to tell Selenium, don't run this at normal speed, run it at a slower speed to allow more things to be available on page load, for slow loading pages or AJAX'ified pages.

Now, you do away with that altogether. Example:

I have a login page, I login and once logged in I see a "Welcome" message. The problem is the Welcome message is not displayed instantly and is on a time delay (using jQuery).

**Pre WebDriver Code** would dictate to Selenium, run this test, but slow down *here* so we can wait until the Welcome message appears.

**Newer WebDriver code** would dictate to Selenium, run this test, but when we login, wait up to 20 seconds for the Welcome Message to appearing, using [explicit waits.](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Now, if you really want access to "set" Selenium's speed, first off I'd recommend against it but the solution would be to dive into the older, now deprecated code.

If you use WebDriver heavily already, you can use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` which can give you access to the older Selenium methods, whilst keeping the WebDriver backing the same, therefore much of your code would stay the same.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/6E53jIIT0TE

Second option is to dive into the old Selenium code and use it, this will change a lot of your existing code (because it is before the "WebDriver" concept was born).

The code for both Selenium RC & WebDriverBackedSelenium lives here, for the curious:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/selenium.py

Something along the lines of:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*webdriver', 'http://www.google.com')
sel.start(driver = driver)
```

You'd then get access to do this:

```
sel.setSpeed(5000)
```

Comment: asap i'll try the backendselenium options. imho it's unbelievable that one can't slow down the entire selenium flow in the newer webdriver code

Comment: it's not unbelievable at all, you shouldn't need to reduce the speed of you tests/automation task.  If it doesn't work because the test is going too fast that just means that the test is badly written and should make use of explicit waits.  It is possible to set an implicit wait on the webdriver object, but this should never be used as it can have unintended side effects, especially if used in conjunction with explicit waits.

Comment: the only reason why i want to reduce the speed is checking the process when the test fails. if i slow the test, i can probably see what happens