# KeyError 'sessionId' when starting phantomJS

Tags: macos, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

Receiving a nice traceback when I attempt to run phamtonjs by itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_selenium.py", line 4, in <module>
    phantom_brow = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test_bed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 58, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test_bed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/test_bed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

Here is ALL of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phantom_brow = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
```

Currently on ElCap behind proxy. Runs with no issues on my Windows parallel though.

Comment: This may to be related to the fact that you are behind a proxy: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1554

Comment: @elethan are there any settings I can load up before I start phantomjs to allow it through the proxy? Adding in the proxy as a service_args hasn't had any effect so far.

Also I should note that Chrome and Firefox WILL load.

Comment: Maybe this solution will help?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545189/3642398