# using selenium to start firefox suffer KeyError: 'sessionId'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

[image]

When I'm using selenium to start firefox, it suffers such a problem. I just write a simple demo to test, by failed.

Comment: my firefox's version is 52.0  and my selenium version is 3.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to update your Selenium version to version 3.3.0 ? 
I had the same problem as yours : changing the proxy settings as mentioned elsewhere did not work, but updating selenium was the solution.

Comment: oh，it works.thank you very very very much.i have no idea at all for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OS X Solution**

If updating did not work for other people, i suggest looking at my answer [Why doesn't Selenium's response have a sessionId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448772/why-doesnt-seleniums-response-have-a-sessionid/42851688#42851688)