# webdriver Firefox opens but gives the Key error: 'sessionid'

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using python version 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0(64-bit)

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("www.google.com")
```

When I execute it from DOS, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "autoRadiatorFirefox.py", line 6, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp)
File "C:\Users\eripflo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "C:\Users\eripflo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\eripflo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

I also tried the following solution stated in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448772/why-doesnt-seleniums-response-have-a-sessionid)

It doesn't work, Firefox opens but it is blank as it fails before it gets to driver.get('.....')

Any help or idea is appreciated :)

Comment: I think you want to use the firefox driver (geckodriver) and not the firefox.exe binary, as the exe is not driveable with selenium

Comment: What version of selenium and what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: @Dean Hi, My firefox version is 52.0.2 and selenium version is  3.3.3

Comment: @mrfreester I tried gecodriver too, I installed it but I don't know how to use it. I came across this example [link here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/) but nothing for python

Comment: After downloading the geckodriver, make sure you add the directory for it to your system path, and then this line should be all you need to set your driver and use it... `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`. Let me know if that works and I'll form it into an answer.

Comment: `driver.get()` takes a URL.   "www.google.com" is not a URL (prepend "https://" to make it one)

Comment: @mrfreester I tried that, but it gives me the following error:
[Link here to Error log](https://snag.gy/s0M8b4.jpg)

Comment: @mrfreester I got the error fixed. I just had to upgrade selenium version to 3.4.0

Comment: @J.Doe Awesome, usually the issue is that the driver needs to be updated, not selenium. Good catch. Feel free to post it as an answer to help others :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @mrfreester,

I just had to upgrade my selenium version from **3.3.3** to **3.4.0**

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same error as OP; Updating selenium resolved the issue.

If you are on macOS like me, and use pip, entering this into terminal should update selenium:

```
pip install -U pip selenium
```

(I would have simply added a comment, but I haven't enough rep points)