# Key Error: Session ID with latest version of GeckoDriver, FF, and Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

I recently upgraded the various pieces of our selenium suite, and when I updated the GeckoDriver to the latest version (0.16.1) I started encountering the following error during set up:

```
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

I know this issue has been brought up here before, but I've checked the other threads and made sure I've followed the correct process.  It seems the universal suggestion is to make sure everything is updated correctly.

I'm using robot framework with a modified version of their Selenium2Library to write and run the tests.

robot version is 3.0.2

selenium version is 3.4.3

FF version is 53.0.3

I have also tried altering my proxy settings following the guidance in the thread here(I am on a mac OS X El Capitan):

[Why doesn't Selenium's response have a sessionId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448772/why-doesnt-seleniums-response-have-a-sessionid/42851688#42851688)

All of this is to no avail.  The only thing I can do to get my tests back to a semi-functional state on firefox is to downgrade the geckodriver.  I'd like to avoid that if possible, since this newest version has some bug fixes helpful to me.

Any guidance on what I should try next?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue with a simple "hello world" type of example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this using the nuclear option -- I did a full uninstall of the three main dependencies in the original question and reinstalled through pip.

Latest versions seem to be in good shape.  For some reason this resolved the underlying keyError.  It does not appear that upgrading the Selenium2Library had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade version of selenium2Library. Current version is 1.8.0

[Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html)

Run Command 
`pip install robotframework-selenium2library  --upgrade`  in cmd
Problem will be solved.